# Find array indices from vector with largest sum

Tags: r, arrays, vector, sum

I have a vector with random real numbers of length 20 generated by:

```
set.seed(100)
vec1 <- runif(20)

 [1] 0.30776611 0.25767250 0.55232243 0.05638315 0.46854928 0.48377074
 [7] 0.81240262 0.37032054 0.54655860 0.17026205 0.62499648 0.88216552
[13] 0.28035384 0.39848790 0.76255108 0.66902171 0.20461216 0.35752485
[19] 0.35947511 0.69029053
```

Then I made a second vector which counts from 1 to 20:

```
vec2 <- 1:20

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I then combine these 2 vectors to make an array:

```
arr1 <- cbind(vec1,vec2)
```

Then I made a list of arrays of dimensions 3x2 so that the elements of the arrays are all adjacent and counting to the end in a for loop (`lis1[[1]]=arr1[1:3,],lis1[[2]]=arr1[2:4,],lis1[[3]]=arr1[3:5,]...lis1[[end]]=arr1[n-2:n,]`)

```
lis1 <- list()
x=1
for (i in 3:length(vec1)) {
  lis1[[x]] <- arr1[(i-2):i,]
  x=x+1
}
```

The I converted that list to a 3D array for convenience:

```
library(abind)
arr2 <- abind(lis1,along=3)
```

The 3D array looks like this:

```
, , 1

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3077661    1
[2,] 0.2576725    2
[3,] 0.5523224    3

, , 2

           vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.25767250    2
[2,] 0.55232243    3
[3,] 0.05638315    4

, , 3

           vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.55232243    3
[2,] 0.05638315    4
[3,] 0.46854928    5

, , 4

           vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.05638315    4
[2,] 0.46854928    5
[3,] 0.48377074    6

, , 5

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.4685493    5
[2,] 0.4837707    6
[3,] 0.8124026    7

, , 6

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.4837707    6
[2,] 0.8124026    7
[3,] 0.3703205    8

, , 7

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.8124026    7
[2,] 0.3703205    8
[3,] 0.5465586    9

, , 8

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3703205    8
[2,] 0.5465586    9
[3,] 0.1702621   10

, , 9

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.5465586    9
[2,] 0.1702621   10
[3,] 0.6249965   11

, , 10

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.1702621   10
[2,] 0.6249965   11
[3,] 0.8821655   12

, , 11

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.6249965   11
[2,] 0.8821655   12
[3,] 0.2803538   13

, , 12

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.8821655   12
[2,] 0.2803538   13
[3,] 0.3984879   14

, , 13

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.2803538   13
[2,] 0.3984879   14
[3,] 0.7625511   15

, , 14

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3984879   14
[2,] 0.7625511   15
[3,] 0.6690217   16

, , 15

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.7625511   15
[2,] 0.6690217   16
[3,] 0.2046122   17

, , 16

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.6690217   16
[2,] 0.2046122   17
[3,] 0.3575249   18

, , 17

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.2046122   17
[2,] 0.3575249   18
[3,] 0.3594751   19

, , 18

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3575249   18
[2,] 0.3594751   19
[3,] 0.6902905   20
```

What I'm trying to find is a piece of code that can find the 2D array in the 3D array in which the `vec1`-column (i.e. `arr2[,1,]`) has the highest sum. I you look at the `arr2`-array this would be the 4th 2D array:

```
, , 14

          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3984879   14
[2,] 0.7625511   15
[3,] 0.6690217   16
```

I would like the output to be:

```
          vec1 vec2
[1,] 0.3984879   14
[2,] 0.7625511   15
[3,] 0.6690217   16
```

So that I can work with both vectors `vec1` and `vec2`. And also, the coordinates vector in the 3D array which is (1st column in the 14th array):

```
[1] 1 14
```

Comment: Something like `arr2[, , which.max(apply(arr2, 2:3, sum)["vec1",])]`? Can't really test because you didn't set the random seed.

Comment: Maybe `arr2[, , which.max(colSums(arr2[, -2, ]))]`?

Comment: Both suggestions answer the first part of my question. Thanks!
I've added "set.seed" now.